# Trigger Brave "Search Tabs" feature from Autohotkey

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey, brave

I would like to be able to trigger "Search Tabs" from Autohotkey, since I have lots of opened tabs this would help me quickly find the tab I am looking for, I know I might be able to loop through all tabs by scripting this, but that's not what I want.

This is what I've done

```
!+a::
  WinActivate, Brave
  Sleep, 100
  Send, {Ctrl}{Shift}a
Return
```

If I change `Send, {Ctrl}{Shift}a` with `Send, {Ctrl}t` is correctly opens a tab, so the problem must be either some error in my `{Ctrl}{Shift}a` configuration or that Brave is somehow not reacting.

Comment: Try **`Send, ^+a`** or **`Send, {Ctrl down}{Shift down}a{Shift up}{Ctrl up}`**

Comment: If **Brave** doesn't exactly match the title af the window you have to add **`SetTitleMatchMode 2`**

Comment: Please write your first comment as answer, it solved my problem! The second one is a configuration I already had. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most appropriate way to activate a specific window and send keystrokes to it is as follows:

```
!+a::
    SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; if you want to use it only in this hotkey
    IfWinNotExist, Brave
    {
        MsgBox, Cannot find Brave
            Return ; end of the hotkey's code
    }
    ; otherwise:
    WinActivate, Brave
    WinWaitActive, Brave, ,2  ; wait 2 seconds maximally  until the specified window is active
    If (ErrorLevel)  ;  if the command timed out
    {
        MsgBox, Cannot activate Brave
            Return
    }
    ; otherwise:
    ; Sleep 300 ; needed in some programs that may not react immediately after activated
    Send, ^+a
Return
```

Otherwise the script can send the keystrokes to another window.

For not repeating the whole code in every hotkey you can create a function:

```
!+b::
    SetTitleMatchMode, 2
    Activate("Brave", 2)
    ; Sleep 300
    Send, ^+a
Return

Activate(title, seconds_to_wait){
    IfWinNotExist, % title
    {
        MsgBox % "Cannot find """ . title . """."
            Return
    }
    ; otherwise:
    WinActivate, % title
    WinWaitActive, % title, ,% seconds_to_wait
    If (ErrorLevel) 
    {
        MsgBox % "Cannot activate """ . title . """."
            Return
    }
}
```